# What is causing 'grunt serve' to throw 'No Bower components found'?

Tags: angularjs, npm, bower

I am starting out angular app with [angular-fullstack](https://www.npmjs.org/package/generator-angular-fullstack) in my Windows 7 box. I installed bunch of npm packages with -g options, including grunt-bower-install. I created the application first by running

> yo angular-fullstack appname

There were no exception during the application creation. After application was created successfully I tried to run the app using

> grunt serve

expecting the server to run. But the 'grunt serve' failed with

> Running "bower-install:app" (bower-install) task
>   Cannot find where you keep your Bower packages.
>
> We tried looking for a `.bowerrc` file, but couldn't find a custom
>   `directory` property defined. We then tried `bower_components`, but
>   it looks like that doesn't exist either. As a last resort, we tried
>   the pre-1.0 `components` directory, but that also couldn't be found.
>
> Unfortunately, we can't proceed without knowing where the Bower
>   packages you have installed are.
>
> **Fatal error: No Bower components found.**

I did find .bowerrc file and it was pointing to app/bower_components. Unfortunately, bower_components file was no where to be found. I am not sure what should be the content of the file to create it myself. Is it the missing file causing this problem or is there a npm package, I did not install correctly?

- I installed bower using npm as well *

Thanks

Comment: run `bower install` from root directory of your app... it will install dependencies to app/bower_components and it should work

Comment: I ran bower install, consequently it throw "bower ECMDERR       Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git, exit code of #128" , I had to run --> git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://   then run --> bower install resolved the issue.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I had the same issue, here's what worked in my case:

1. installed ruby and compass (yeoman needs these)
2. verified that path to Ruby bin folder is added to %PATH%
3. installed Git
4. restarted cmd window and ran "bower install" in the app folder

After that, grunt serve command worked perfectly.
Note: maybe installing Git and running bower install would suffice in your case.

Comment: I also needed Ruby and Compass (specific version as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22554220/compass-error-for-command-grunt-server ) to get grunt serve working.

Comment: Worth precising, you need to install bower

Comment: Specifically, you should only need Ruby and Compass if you choose the (default) sass option when you run the generator. I have it working just fine without either.

Answer (score 70):

Confusingly, the grunt-bower-install task that comes with angular-fullstack doesn't install bower components. It doesn't install anything. This error is trying to let you know that it can't find the bower_components directly, so it can't do its thing.

To fix the issue, run `bower install`.

If you don't have Bower installed, run `npm install -g bower` first.

Comment: I forgot about the `bower install`. This helped my remember. Thanks!

Comment: where do you run bower install to, root of the webapp directory?

Comment: Yeah, just run the command anywhere in your project directory (doesn't have to be the root) and the components will be installed in a directory named "bower_components" wherever bower.json is located.

Answer (score 12):

I faced the same problem but only did `npm install -g bower` and then `bower install` and got `grunt serve` working.

I did not need to do any of the things mentioned by Olga.

Hope this helps.

Comment: She did say to do `bower install` though!

Answer (score 5):

`npm install -g bower` doesn't install bower components, you should run as well `bower install` to have all bower's components installed and then run `grunt serve`. It should work fine

Answer (score 3):

Try to do `bower install`. If its failing saying not able to connect to git then you can change repo pointing location by simply running below command

```
$ git config --global url.https://github.com/.insteadOf git://github.com/
```

This will ensure that you will be downloaded over https instead of git if its causing orginasation firewall to block it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I added `sudo` for it to work. So, I ran `sudo npm install -g bower`and then `bower install`. `grunt serve` then worked when I ran it.

Answer (score 1):

The Bower installation requires the packages to be brought from the Git repository, so first you need to install the Git application in your system. You can download it from this link :https://git-scm.com/downloads . Now after your have downloaded it , there may be a chance that the PATH may not be set up, so go to ControlPanel -> System and Security -> System -> Advance System Settings (on the left-hand side), click it, then goto Environment Variables -> System Variables -> PATH , click edit , and write down the following paths :

;C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin;
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd ....Well the above path is where Git was installed in my system, you can crawl to the place in your system where Git was installed and select the paths from the "bin" and "cmd" folder and paste it on the PATH variable.

Now, after the GIT path is setup, you can now type in the command " $ bower install " , this will install all of your bower packages.

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install -g bower
bower install
grunt serve
```

worked for me ...

Answer (score -1):

```
npm install -g bower
bower install
grunt serve
```

It's worked too