# Compass error for command 'grunt server'

Tags: ruby, node.js, gruntjs, yeoman, compass-sass

I'm running a project for which I installed nodeJs, ruby, yeoman, compass, etc. Now Im running my project with command
`>grunt server` or `>grunt server --force`

but it is giving me following error for compass.

```
E:\CRM_workspace\CRM_from_repo\ria>grunt server --force
Running "server" task
>> The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.

Running "serve" task

Running "clean:server" (clean) task
Cleaning .tmp...OK

Running "concurrent:server" (concurrent) task

Running "copy:styles" (copy) task


Done, without errors.

Running "compass:server" (compass) task
directory .tmp/styles/
       create .tmp/styles/main.css (3.069s)
    Warning: ↑ Used --force, continuing.

Done, but with warnings.

Running "autoprefixer:dist" (autoprefixer) task

Running "connect:livereload" (connect) task
Started connect web server on 127.0.0.1:9000.

Running "watch" task
Waiting...
```

I tried uninstalling and installing compass and sass. but still the same error for `'compass:server'`

What do i need to do?

this is the details error I got:

```
E:\CRM_workspace\CRM_from_repo\ria>grunt serve
Running "serve" task

Running "clean:server" (clean) task

Running "concurrent:server" (concurrent) task

Running "copy:styles" (copy) task


Done, without errors.
    Warning: Errno::EACCES on line ["891"] of C: Permission denied - (E:/CRM_wor
kspace/CRM_from_repo/ria/.tmp/styles/main.css20140321-4456-1klow8l, E:/CRM_works
pace/CRM_from_repo/ria/.tmp/styles/main.css)
    Run with --trace to see the full backtrace Use --force to continue.

    Aborted due to warnings.


Execution Time (2014-03-21 11:21:08 UTC)
concurrent:server  6.3s  ■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■ 100%
Total 6.3s
```

Comment: I also get this after updating compass and sass

Comment: Got the answer for this problem on this link : 
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22596760/yeoman-error-errnoeacces-on-line-897-of-c-permission-denied/22597296#22597296

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an issue with Compass 0.12.4.

Follow the issue here: https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/1618

You need to uninstall compass 0.12.4: `gem uninstall compass`, and then install the latest working release: `gem install compass -v 0.12.3`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not working on windows, but best guess it seems like ruby doesn't have write permission to your target directory `E:/CRM_workspace/CRM_from_repo/ria/.tmp/styles/main.css`, so check for that. I don't know about permission control under windows, maybe you should give ruby administrator rights or let `E:` for everyone writable.

UPDATE: As far as I know, this problem is related with sass's version, so try to update your compass to `v3.2.18` at least.

You check the current version with command: `gem list sass`, and update with command: `gem update sass`, good luck and keep me posted.

Comment: @Piyusha Sorry, but I don't know about windows too much, maybe the latter options is more common, enable the write permission of `E:` for everyone.

Comment: I tried with permissions but it seems C: drive and E: drive both have permissions for read and write. My Ruby was installed in C: drive before. And now I uninstalled and installed everything on E: drive only. And now the error has changed from "EACCES on line ["891"] of C: Permission denied" to "EACCES on line ["891"] of E: Permission denied". It means I have to change ruby administrator rights. Do you know how to do it ?

Comment: Yupp... I felt the same that it must be related to compass.  I tried the answer on this link and it worked. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22596760/yeoman-error-errnoeacces-on-line-897-of-c-permission-denied/22597296#22597296   Thank you so much.