# Yeoman error: "Errno::EACCES on line ["897"] of C: Permission denied"

Tags: sass, gruntjs, compass-sass, yeoman

I upgraded my hardware yesterday and fresh installed Win 8.1. This error is killing me since then. I already lost full day of work trying to figure out what's going on. I never encountered this on my Mac or in my old Win 7 machine.

Setting up a new project with `yo webapp` using **Bootstrap** and **Modernizr** works great. Server would fire-up and I can see my updates livereload. But, setting up a new project with **Compass and SASS** included would prevent me from starting local server and throw this error:

```
D:\test>grunt serve
Running "serve" task

Running "clean:server" (clean) task

Running "concurrent:server" (concurrent) task

Running "copy:styles" (copy) task

Done, without errors.
    Warning: Errno::EACCES on line ["897"] of C: Permission denied - (D:/test/.t
mp/styles/main.css20140323-6060-d9r9eo, D:/test/.tmp/styles/main.css)
    Run with --trace to see the full backtrace Use --force to continue.

    Aborted due to warnings.


Execution Time (2014-03-23 20:05:00 UTC)
concurrent:server  4.8s  ■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■ 100%
Total 4.8s

D:\test>
```

I updated Compass and SASS to latest version, reinstalled Yeoman & Ruby, and tried bunch of other small tweaks. Nothing worked.

Any ideas what else I could try?

Comment: I submitted an alternate solution to this problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22597223/errnoeaccess-permission-denied-running-compass-watch

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I have found solution for this issue. I guess this might help with other similar problems running grunt server. This is what did it for me:

Uninstall SASS

```
gem uninstall sass
```

Uninstall COMPASS

```
gem uninstall compass
```

Install --pre COMPASS version

```
gem install compass --pre
```

Install --pre SASS version

```
gem install sass --pre
```

For some reason only running task in this order worked for me. I hope this helps.

Comment: I was having the same issue and these steps also corrected the problem for me.

Comment: I have the new issue:LoadError on line ["55"] of C: cannot load such file -- wdm, I tried to install it via DevKit but DevKit can't install it, anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: This did not work for me, but the answer here did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22597223/errnoeaccess-permission-denied-running-compass-watch

Answer (score 2):

Issue is solved in SASS 3.2.19
Try `gem update compass`

Comment: I can confirm that. Issue was solved after upgrading SASS from 3.2.17 to 3.2.19.