# Grunt EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - How to set permissions on ubuntu?

Tags: node.js, sass, gruntjs

I just did a fresh digital ocean droplet creation. I have the latest everything - and am getting this EACCESS error when I run my grunt. The grunt script just runs grunt-contrib-sass v1.0. I've used this grunt script before - works in other environments. I have sass 3.4.22 installed but don't know how to debug this.

```
Grunt env is  production
Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - public/builds/style.css
  Use --trace for backtrace.
Warning: Exited with error code 1 Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.


Execution Time (2016-11-08 08:47:40 UTC)
```

What is rb_sysopen and why is it complaining about it when I run sass?

Comment: The first two things I would check is that (1) the user running grunt has write access to the file specified and (2) there is not another process locking the file

Comment: (and the third thing I would check is that the target path public/builds exists)

Comment: I have root - def have access. How can I check if a process is locking the file? This is a fresh digital oceans droplet - don't think anythings locking it.  Also, the paths exist

Comment: try `touch public/builds/style.css` - does that have any issues?

Comment: Looks like the following related SO question has an answer you can try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22596760/yeoman-error-errnoeacces-on-line-897-of-c-permission-denied?rq=1

Comment: @binarymax when I sudo touch - no issues. Still can't grunt without calling sudo. Problem is my NODE_ENV gets set to undefined causing my grunt scripts to barf