# Yeoman - Grunt Angular Generator : Compass Serve Error

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, bower, yeoman-generator, yo

I've been looking through error reports all day and re-reading posts on here and error reports on GitHub and not finding an answer to my problem.

**Error**

```
Running "concurrent:server" (concurrent) task
    Warning: >> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-compass" not found. Is it installed?
    Warning: Task "compass:server" not found. Use --force to continue.

    Aborted due to warnings.


    Execution Time (2015-02-18 20:46:22 UTC)
    loading tasks  3ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 75%
    Total 4ms Use --force to continue.

        Aborted due to warnings.


Execution Time (2015-02-18 20:46:21 UTC)
wiredep:app        137ms  ▇▇▇▇ 7%
concurrent:server   1.7s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 91%
Total 1.8s
```

**What I have Tried**

Since the install couldn't find it to install it the first time, I reinstalled using bower install --save 
After that I can't get anything to work.

**Here is a copy of my Grunt.js**

https://gist.github.com/ddavisgraphics/8fc9bb3958317f1fd06b

**bower.json**

https://gist.github.com/ddavisgraphics/d0828b048e2ac4543758

Comment: This must be installed using npm not bower, npm install grunt-contrib-compass --same-sex

Comment: Thanks man.  That worked.  Now I have an issue with my rubygems, but I think that was another question I ran into earlier.

EDIT: I actually only had to do sudo npm install and it made all necessary packages.

Comment: Solved the Ruby Gems Issue with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22554220/compass-error-for-command-grunt-server

Comment: was --save-dev the phone change it