# grunt error when running "grunt serve" with generator-angular-fullstack seed

Tags: javascript, git, gruntjs, bower, angular-seed

I have been working with [this](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack) seed, and I haven't had this error before, and I have issued the `grunt serve` command countless times - I am only now getting this error. The only thing I did that could be causing it is I deleted the directory with my project in it - and used `git clone` to clone the repo that I am storing my project because I wanted to revert to an older version. Now I get this error:

```
Cannot find where you keep your Bower packages.

We tried looking for a `.bowerrc` file, but couldn't find a custom
`directory` property defined. We then tried `bower_components`, but
it looks like that doesn't exist either. As a last resort, we tried
the pre-1.0 `components` directory, but that also couldn't be found.

Unfortunately, we can't proceed without knowing where the Bower
packages you have installed are.

Fatal error: No Bower components found.
```

I have a `bower_components` directory (where it should be) - I'm not sure why it isn't being seen. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367837/what-is-causing-grunt-serve-to-throw-no-bower-components-found) on stack - but it doesn't seem to be my problem, I tried running `bower install` - it didn't throw any errors, but it didn't fix the problem either. Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I think I realized what happened, but I'm not sure what to do about it (other than reinstall from the seed and copy over all my code). I think the seed (by default) leaves out files when I push to git (maybe the `.bowerrc` file?) - so when I cloned I didn't get all the files I needed - any suggestions for remedying this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Suggestion is to run

```
npm update
```

Hopefully you will see it installing everything for you.

follow that up with a

```
bower install
```

this should fix your issue as long as your repo has the bower.json file in it- though like me you may be finding under the default grunt (tests) the karma.conf.js is missing.

the contents of the .bowerrc if you need it are just

```
{
    "directory": "app/bower_components"
}
```