# Grunt serve not working after updating gruntfile.js update

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, bower, wiredep

when i run grunt serve it will send msg below and server doesnt run

Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task
Cannot find where you keep your Bower packages

I went through google found out solution to comment

```
wiredep: {
  options: {
    //cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>'
  },
  app: {
    src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
    ignorePath:  /\.\.\//
  },
  sass: {
    src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
    ignorePath: /(\.\.\/){1,2}bower_components\//
  }
}
```

but still get same msg

thanks

Comment: Have you run `bower install` to install bower packages? This looks like wiredep couldn't find your `bower_components` folder.

Comment: It was something to do with company router not allowing to go through some of the github url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, here's what worked in my case:

1. Installed ruby and compass (yeoman needs these)
2. Verified that path to Ruby bin folder is added to %PATH%
3. Installed Git
4. Restarted cmd window and ran "bower install" in the app folder

After that, grunt serve command worked perfectly. Note: maybe installing Git and running bower install would suffice in your case.

My answer follow this article: [What is causing 'grunt serve' to throw 'No Bower components found'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367837/what-is-causing-grunt-serve-to-throw-no-bower-components-found)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have `.bowerrc` file in your project root directory. This file points `bower` where to store the packages when you run `bower install`.

Comment: It something to do with router blocking git URL on doing bower install it's fixed now thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try running bower update && npm install in your app directory if that does not fix it post all your Gruntfile.js

Answer (score 0):

try removing anything in cwd in wiredep section of your Grutfile.js

```
wiredep: {
      options: {
        cwd: ''
      },
      app: {
        src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
        ignorePath:  /\.\.\//
      }
```